# Strict partial order and strict linear order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

**Task :

A binary relation on a set of 7 elements contains exactly 20 pairs.

Could it be :

a) a strict partial order relation?

b) a relation of strict linear order?**

In strict linear order, any pair of distinct elements is comparable.

**My thinking :**

a) There can be a total of $7 \times (7 - 1) / 2 = 21$ pairs of elements. We are given $20$ pairs of elements. Since a strict partial order does not have to be linear, it is very likely that a strict partial order can be created. I can't give any other arguments. Maybe I need to demonstrate some example of strictly partial order on $7$ elements with $20$ pairs to prove the existence of a strictly partial order relation?

b) It seems that there certainly cannot be a strict linear linear order relation, because for that , each pair must be comparable, that is, there must be at least $7 \times (7 - 1) / 2 = 21$ pairs of elements. We have only $20$ pairs, but we need $21$ pairs, one pair is missing, so there is no strict linear order relationship. Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: Your response to b is correct. A strict linear order on $N$ elements will have exactly $\binom{N}{2}$ pairs. 

For a, in the absence of some general result saying that a relation can be a strict partial order if and only if it has at most $\binom{N}{2}$ elements, it would be necessary to come up with an example.

Comment: Is it possible to solve point a without giving an example? Maybe there are some properties of strict partial order that can be used?

Comment: Giving an example is often the easiest way to prove things like this. Why do you want some other way?

Comment: In general, yes, it could be possible to prove existence without coming up with a specific example. In this case, you could potentially use the properties of a strict partial order to show that a relation on a set with $N$ elements having at most $\binom{N}{2}$ comes from some strict partial order. But I think that in this case, it would still look essentially the same as coming up with an explicit example. And examples are not too difficult to come by in this case. Start with the full order and delete one relation without losing transitivity.

Comment: (1) You are right : It can never be strict linear order due to missing $1$ relation out of $21$. (2) Prove that strict partial order is possible by using elements $1,2,3,4,5,6$ with some arbitrary strict linear order & then make the new element $VI$ which is comparable with $1,2,3,4,5$ exactly like $6$ & then claim that $VI$ is not comparable with $6$.

Comment: You have given what strict linear order mean. You should also give what strict partial order means. Ideally you should give the Exact Definition unambiguously !

Comment: Different Authors & Different Books will have Different Definitions !